# The probabilities of components A, B, C, D and E working are 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8 and 0.8, respectively. What is the probability that:

Tags: probability

[image]

An electrical circuit has 5 components labelled A, B, C, D and E. The probabilities of components A, B, C, D and E working are 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8 and 0.8, respectively. What is the probability that:

- (a) The system will be working.
- (b) Component A will not be working given that the system is working.
- (c) Component A will not be working given that the system is not working.

I solved but I'm not sure it is correct.

- (a)
  W is event that the system will be working
  \begin{align}
   & P(W) \\
  ={}& P(A \cap B \cup C \cap D \cap E)\\
  ={}& P(A \cap B) + P(C \cap D \cap E) - P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D \cap E)\\
  ={}& 0.7^2 + 0.8^3 - 0.7^2 0.8^3\\
  ={}& 0.75112
  \end{align}
- (b)
  \begin{align}
   & P(\bar{A}|W) \\
  ={}& \frac{P(\bar{A} \cap W)}{P(W)}\\
  ={}& \frac{P(\bar{A}BCDE \cup \bar{A} \bar{B}CDE)}{P(W)}\\
  ={}& \frac{0.3\times0.7\times0.8^3 + 0.3^2\times0.8^3}{0.75112}\\
  ={}& \frac{1920}{9389}
  \end{align}
- Is my answer for (a) and (b) correct?
- How to solve (c)?

Comment: part a looks good. Part b, I'm not sure what your writing is supposed to represent in the third line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure gives $P(C)=0.8$ but the question says $P(C)=0.7$.

Your answers are correct according to the figure but there are some typos: in $(a)$ it should be $P(A\cap B\cup C\cap D\cap E)$ as taking union of probabilities does not make sense. In $(b)$, judging from your calculation and assuming $XY$ is shorthand for $X\cap Y$, you probably meant to have $P(\bar ABCDE\color{red}\cup\color{blue}{\bar A\bar B}CDE)$ in the numerator. Note that $\overline{AB}\ne\bar A\bar B$.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. I have just added the (c) one and I do not know how to solve it. Could you take a look?

Comment: @null to find $P(\bar A|\bar W)$ simply use the fact $P(\bar A)=0.3=P(\bar A|W)P(W)+P(\bar A|\bar W)P(\bar W)$ which follows from the fact that $W,\bar W$ are mutually disjoint, exhaustive events.